# Applying a plotly dendrogram to text data

Tags: python, text, plotly, dendrogram, plotly-python

I'm trying to create a dendrogram as demonstrated [here](https://plot.ly/python/dendrogram/), using text data rather than numeric.

This simple example works:

```
from plotly import figure_factory as ff

ff.create_dendrogram(
    X=np.array([ [1], [2], [3] ]),
)
```

Similarly, I try to use text data, with a defined distance function:

```
from difflib import ndiff

ff.create_dendrogram(
    X=np.array([ ['foo'], ['bar'], ['baz'] ]),
    distfun=lambda x, y: len(list(ndiff(x, y))),    # e.g. len(list(ndiff('bar', 'baz'))) --> 4
)
```

But it raises the following error:

```
TypeError: <lambda>() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.

`create_dendrogram` expected a distance function (`distfun`) with a signature like [**`pdist`**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html).

So this fixed it:

```
from functools import partial
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist

ff.create_dendrogram(
    X=np.array([ ['foo'], ['bar'], ['baz'] ]),
    distfun=partial(pdist, metric=lambda x, y: len(list(ndiff(x, y)))),
)
```